# Citing a cited reference

Tags: bibtex

How would I go about doing this in BibTeX -

http://www.reading.ac.uk/library/finding-info/guides/lib-citing-cited-ref.aspx

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all learning to use bibtex, later finding what's the citation style you need to use.

Comment: Perhaps the `cross-ref` or `x-ref` field would do what you want. You then should use `biblatex`+`biber`. See § 2.4.1 of the documentation of biblatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. @Bernard `crossref` works with `bibtex`.... With `biblatex`, `related` might be helpful. With `bibtex`, you could just use the `note` field.

Comment: `\cite[x], cited by \cite[y]`?

Comment: I'd follow the recommendation **You should keep cited references to an absolute minimum** and set this minimum to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `natbib`, which has many features, and BibTeX.

The bibtex file (`ex.bib`) is for example:

```
@Article{john_doe,
 author = {{Doe}, J.},
 title = "{\it Some title}",
 journal = {Book or journal},
 year = {2014},
 volume = "{\bf 1}",
 pages = {5--10},
}
```

And the source file (`ex.tex`) is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Some text here \citep[cited by][]{john_doe}.


\bibliographystyle{apalike} %just an example of citation style
\bibliography{ex}{}

\end{document}
```

Which will produce this two-page file:

[image: 1st page]

[image: 2nd page]

But remember, that it is not morally correct to cite publications that you did not read.

Comment: @pwlaslo Is this the answer you were looking for? If so, please, mark it as accepted. If no, let us know in the comment. Thanks.